# Managing / Hiding Specific Assembly Dependies

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I've been working on refactoring an existing codebase and am stuck on how to hide / avoid referencing an external utility in ALL my projects. Specifically, i'm employing a pattern using castle's dictionary adapter to get config dependencies:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AppSettingsFromConfigAttribute : Attribute, IDictionaryBehavior, IDictionaryPropertyGetter, IPropertyDescriptorInitializer, IDictionaryKeyBuilder
{
....
}
```

where all the specified interfaces are coming from Castle.Core. The usage of this attribute though all my projects just becomes something like:

```
[AppSettingsFromConfig("gpg:")]
public interface IGPGConfiguration
{
    string HomeDirectory { get; set; }
    string KeyDirectory { get; set; }
}
```

which nominally gets me gpg:HomeDirectory and gpg:KeyDirectory from a config file.

My problem is if the AppSettingsFromConfigAttribute is defined in my "Utility" dll, all my projects (using this feature) need to refer *both* Utlity.dll and Castle.Core to compile - which i just don't like, it's an explicit reference to Castle.Core that ends up coming all over my codebase.... for interfaces none of the projects care about, only the castle bootstrapper needs them.

In short - class implements a bunch of external interfaces no one cares about except for 1 (external) guy, but rest N customers end up needing the external reference to compile, and i just don't like that behaviour.

So how do i avoid it? or am i missing something trivial?

Comment: The best way to avoid referencing an external dependency deep in a hierarchy is to do it as far out as possible and pass the result in. This can cause you to use more complicated data objects as parameters, but ultimately leads to cleaner, more testable code with fewer dependencies.

Comment: @Magus - Can you explain what that means in my context? I need a marker attribute throughout my projects, the interfaces implemented by it are used only at one place, the main bootstrap, by an external framework. My problem is those are causing me to add a fixed external dependency everywhere, just for compilation.

Comment: And so, to repeat myself, in the bootstrapper you get the value. Then you pass that value down, rather than using an attribute, because the attribute will cause that dependency. If just the value is passed along as a parameter to methods, no dependency will be created.

Comment: Avoid the attributes, fair enough. But i have no control over Castle's Dictionary adapter - it uses that attribute / interfaces internally. So there's no simple answer from the organization side then, i'll have to dig around the Castle Adapter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated from the answers, you just can't do it, especially with attributes, it will always be two dependencies (which at most you could mush into a single DLL). So i've changed the structure to use:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AppSettingsFromConfigAttribute : Attribute {}
```

as a simple marker. Looked at the Windsor source and all the interfaces implemented were internally being used to add a PropertyDescriptor to the type when making the dictionary adapter. Windsor being windsor provides an overload to specify a PropertyDescriptor externally, so i now create that myself at runtime using the vanilla attribute, in the bootstrapper - the one place that needs Castle.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because `IDictionaryBehavior` and such are part of the definition of `AppSettingsFromConfigAttribute`. If you want the consumers of the attribute to not have a dependency on Castle.Core, then you need to remove that from the class definition.

You could then perhaps use `Castle.Core` dynamically in the attribute.

Comment: Those interfaces are needed by the Castle Dictionary adapter to work. So can't remove them. What do you mean by use Castle.Core dynamically? Load dynamically to use functionality? All i need are the shared interface definitions....

Comment: But the interface definitions are required in order for the users of your attribute class to use the class. They are part of its definition and cannot be ignored. These interfaces are as much a part of the definition of the attribute as the name of the attribute itself.

Comment: See that's the part i'm not so happy with. Yes i understand it's part of the necessary metadata and needs to be loaded for the class definition to be complete, but it works against my goal of cutting out or managing external dependencies and i have no clue of how to write an adapter / facade around attributes, nor can i control Castle's usage of those interfaces.

Comment: Here's another way to think about it. What if your attribute class implemented a .NET interface? The users of that attribute would have a dependency on the assembly containing the interface definition. It's not about third party dependencies.